# textbox validation in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello i´m new to google apps script and i would to compare, the value that i put in the Textboxes with the value in the excel sheet. The values of my excel sheet are correcty display and the textboxes are correcty created (two because there are two entries in the excel sheet). I would to validate this: if what i put in my textboxes are greater than the value of excel sheet then error else it´s ok. And i would like to use a submit button. I saw an example with a validate email function but i cannot transform that, to my example.
And when i debub the function validateStock(e) i get parameter" undefined.
Please help me.

```
function doGet() {
 var user = Session.getUser().getUserLoginId();
 var excel = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Alg06LrHGRkddDJyMUh5bGRsZnhKQkpqYjBCN0d0X2c");
 var raw = excel.getSheets()[0];

 var app = UiApp.createApplication();
 var stockLabel = app.createLabel('Introduza a Quantidade de Stock pretendida');
 var inputBox = app.createTextBox().setId('stockBox').setName('myStock');
 var submitButton = app.createButton('Validate');
 var infoLabel = app.createLabel('Stock é Valido').setVisible(false).setId('info');
 var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();

 var list = raw.getRange("A1:A2").getValues();

 for( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)  
 {
 //if (list[i] == user) 

 var cliente = raw.getSheetValues(i+1,2,1,1);
 app.add(app.createLabel("Stock: "+ list[i]));
 app.add(app.createTextBox());

 //raw.getSheetValues(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns)

 }
 panel.add(stockLabel)
.add(inputBox)
.add(infoLabel)
.add(submitButton);

//Add the panel to the application
//Create Click handlet and add to the submit button
var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('validateStock');
handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
submitButton.addClickHandler(handler);

panel.add(stockLabel).add(inputBox).add(submitButton);
app.add(panel);
return app;
}

//Function to validate stock and display the response
function validateStock(e){
var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
var excel = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Alg06LrHGRkddDJyMUh5bGRsZnhKQkpqYjBCN0d0X2c");
var raw = excel.getSheets()[0];
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var list = raw.getRange("A1:A2").getValues();
stock = e.parameter.myStock;
Logger.log(stock);

if(emailPattern.test(stock) == false)

app.getElementById('info').setText("Invalid Email Address").setStyleAttribute("color",   "#F00").setVisible(true);
  else
    app.getElementById('info').setText("Valid Email Address").setStyleAttribute('color', '#339900').setVisible(true);
return app;
}
  else
    app.getElementById('info').setText("Valid Email Address").setStyleAttribute('color', '#339900').setVisible(true);
return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug using the logger. You cant debug validateStock with the debugger because it is a call back. (Last time I checked,  the debugger does not work with call back functions)

To use the debugger, you could add a function a bit like this:

```
function debugValidateStock(e){
 var e.parameter.myStock = "test";
 validateStock(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 -You have to initialize the variable STOCK :

`stock = e.parameter.myStock;`**-->** `var stock = e.parameter.myStock`

2 - To run the program without considering the parameter e.parameter.myStock and the callback function , you have to def the var myStock in the beginning of the function **validateStock**

`var stock  = "*WHAT_YOU_EXPECT*" ;`  instead of `stock = e.parameter.myStock;`